# Allow sorting questions in the featured tab by favorite/ignored tag

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, sorting, ignored-tags, bountied-tab

Please consider letting us order featured questions in a way that is based on your list of favorite and ignored tags:

- **Favorites-First Sort** - orders questions that have one or more tags among your favorites ahead of questions that do not have any such tags. Questions with tags on both favorite and ignored lists are considered favorite.
- **Ignored-Last Sort** - orders questions that have one or more tags among your ignored tags after questions that do not have any such tags. Questions with tags on both favorite and ignored lists are considered ignored.

The rest of the sorting order should remain the same (i.e. questions expiring in the next 24 hours should be at the top, higher bounties have somewhat higher priority, and so on).